# mql4 - How to read .txt file into mql variable

Tags: readfile, mql4, mql

variable.txt file :

10;20;30;40;50

how to import the variable.txt into mql4 variable

a=10

b=20

c=30

d=40

e=50

thank you

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061059/integrating-the-ohlc-value-from-python-api-to-mt5-using-mql5/51199962#51199962 ? Skip python and use only MQL4/5 part of the answer, if you need to parse some message manually -`getSymbolFromFileName()` function shows what to do

Comment: can you help me, with the basic simple code?
thank you

Comment: all the code is there. copy and paste, add debug when you received a message and tell us what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

This does not reproduce the lettering indicated in your suggested output, but is perhaps a more useful example in general:

```
  ResetLastError();
  int next_int = 0;
  int filehandle = FileOpen("variable.txt",FILE_READ|FILE_CSV|FILE_ANSI);
  if( filehandle != INVALID_HANDLE ) {
    while(!FileIsLineEnding(file_handle) && !FileIsEnding(file_handle)) {
      next_int = StringToInteger(FileReadString(filehandle));
      Print("the next int is ",next_int);
    } // while
    FileClose(filehandle);
  } // if
  else {
    Print("FileOpen('variable.txt') failed, error= ",GetLastError());
  } // else
```

Review the MQL4 documentation for [FileOpen()](https://docs.mql4.com/files/fileopen), [FileIsLineEnding()](https://docs.mql4.com/files/fileislineending) and [FileReadString()](https://docs.mql4.com/files/filereadstring) for more clarity.
Note the opened file path is relative to the MetaTrader4 Terminal path, as described in doc for [FileOpen()](https://docs.mql4.com/files/fileopen).